# SetInterval keeps running in webcomponent when element is not present in dom anymore

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval, web-component

At the moment, I am working on a simple application that orchestrates multiple webcomponents. One of these components holds a setInterval function. The function keeps running, even when the component itself is not present in the dom anymore. Can one explain to me why this is the case?

Here is a simple reproduction:

```
const selectorEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
selectorEl.innerHTML = '<my-component></my-component>'; // Append custom component to body

class WebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.innerHTML = '<span>This should not be visible since I am removed instantly!</span>';
        setInterval(() => console.log('I am still running...'), 2000);
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-component', WebComponent);
selectorEl.innerHTML = ''; // Remove element from the dom directly
```

Comment: `setInterval` will always run until you call `clearInterval`, it has nothing to do with the DOM.

Comment: _"The function keeps running, even when the component itself is not present in the dom anymore. Can one explain to me why this is the case?"_ - because there is absolutely no relation between those two things ...?!? You instructed the browser to execute a function in an interval, from now on. What would the DOM have to do with this ...?

Comment: Thanks, Keith. Do you know if it is possible to stop all running intervals inside webcomponents with force, if they are not cleaning up this logic?

Comment: You will likely want to use the lifecycle callbacks,,   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks

Comment: @CBroe My confusion is the following: I thought that a web component is an encapsulated piece of code, especially when it has a shadow dom, that has nothing to do with the parent. Hence, if the component does not exist anymore, I was thinking that the whole logic was not present anymore, and could be garbage collected...

Comment: @Keith I imagine he's not in control of the component (cf. "_if they are not cleaning up this logic_")

Comment: No, that is not how it works. Web component / shadow DOM do not create a separate `window` instance. And `setInterval` is a method of `window`.

Comment: @Tom If you don't control the web components with leaky timers, you can [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) the window timers ([timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)) in order to maintain your own timer ID list and clear them according to your own criteria.

Comment: @jsejcksn Sounds brilliant, will try that! Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [lifecycle callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) to correctly use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.

Example below:

```js
const selectorEl = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
selectorEl.innerHTML = "<my-component></my-component>"; // Append custom component to body

class WebComponent extends HTMLElement {

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML =
      "<span>This should not be visible since I am removed instantly!</span>";
  
    this.interval = setInterval(
      () => console.log("I am still running...", Math.random()),
      2000
    );
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

window.customElements.define("my-component", WebComponent);
setTimeout(() => selectorEl.innerHTML = "",7000); // Remove element from the dom directly
```

Comment: WARNING! This code fails on ``document.createElement("my-component");`` because the ``constructor`` should not add DOM elements, that work should be done in the ``connectedCallback``. Only when you create a **shadowRoot** in your ``conctructor`` can you add HTML (to shadowDOM)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, thank you so much for your attention to the problem. I missed this point and corrected it in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **disconnectedCallback** hook it will get called once the component will get removed from the dom, so in this function, you can clear your interval.

```
disconnectedCallback() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Components have their own lifecycle and when an element is deleted from the DOM `disconnectedCallback()` get's called. is  lifecycle hook is called when the element is removed from the DOM. hence, it’s an ideal place to add cleanup logic and to free up resources. in your case, call the `clearInterval` method which clears a timer set with the setInterval() method like you did.

```
disconnectedCallback() {
   clearInterval(interval)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more concise example:

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log("connectedCallback" , this.isConnected);
      this.innerHTML = "A Web Component";
      setTimeout(() => this.remove(), 2000); // triggers disconnectedCallback
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this.innerHTML += ".", 50);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
      console.log("disconnectedCallback" , this.isConnected);
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  });
</script>
<my-component></my-component>
```

Notes

- The DOM element no longer exists in the `disconnectedCallback`, but the Web Component stills exists in memory, so you can access anything that was created(or attached) prior
- Drag/drop or `append` operations trigger the `disconnectedVCallback` **and then** the `connectedCallback` again